# Access CanCan's `can?` method from a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

You can get the `current_user`'s permissions from a view or controller using `can?` in this fashion:

```
  <% if can? :update, @article %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
  <% end %>
```

How can I access this functionality from a model using this syntax:

```
user.can?(:update, @article)
```

Comment: Good question. Glad you also got a good answer on it!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There's a wiki entry at github for this: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/ability-for-other-users

You need to change your User model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def ability
    @ability ||= Ability.new(self)
  end
  delegate :can?, :cannot?, :to => :ability
end
```

Then you can check abilities like this:

```
user.can?(:update,@article)
```

Comment: For CanCanCan: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Ability-for-Other-Users