# undefined method current_user: Cancan and Active Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, cancan, scaffold

I'm trying to add an action link to an active scaffold controller using

```
if current_user.can? :update, Post
  config.action_links.add 'export', :label => 'Export', :page => true
end
```

but whatever controller I try to use, I always get `undefined method current_user`
So, how can I check if the logged user can/cannot do something?
I've even tried with

```
def ability
  @ability ||= Ability.new(self)
end
delegate :can?, :cannot?, :to => :ability
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293400/access-cancans-can-method-from-a-model), but without success.
What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current_user is a typically defined method, but it is one that you must add. it is not supplied by rails. So, you need a current_user method in your ApplicationController. There are tons of examples but I would look at the [authlogic example app on github](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example)

Comment: I'm using Devise, and not Authlogic: is it the same?

Comment: take a look at the devise example app on github. if it is not the same, it is very similar.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the normal case ActiveScaffold config is done in the class not the instance so there is no current_user set because there is no request yet.