# Limit children in awesome_nested_set by cancan ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a model that acts as a nested set (tree), like so:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :parent_id
  acts_as_nested_set  

  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Position', :foreign_key => :parent_id
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Position', :foreign_key => :parent_id
end
```

My ability.rb file contains this:

```
can :read, Position, :id => #a list of position ids
```

The list of ids will change depending on another setting that is not important to this situation.

My question is, how do get @position.children to only return those positions that are authorized in the ability?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want conditions on the `has_many` within a lambda so it evaluates at run time...  Something like:

```
has_many :children, :class_name => 'Position', :foreign_key => :parent_id, :conditions => lambda {|child| can? :read child }
```

I haven't tested this (obviously) but this should get you closer.

To get `can?` available in a model, see: [Access CanCan's `can?` method from a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293400/access-cancans-can-method-from-a-model)

Comment: I don't think you can use 'can?' within a model. Unless you know of a way?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293400/access-cancans-can-method-from-a-model